# Centrar uma imagem que fica demasiado grande para o ecrâ?

Tags: css

Eu tenho uma imagem que tem um `height` de `100%`. No entanto, o `width` ultrapassa os limites laterais e a imagem fica cortada do lado direito e eu gostaria de a centrar para cortar igualmente dos dois lados. Eis um [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paeyh0fk/) que fiz para demonstração

Comment: Vc quer centralizar o background no Body, ou quer centralizar um elemento que tem uma imagem dentro no centro do Body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar como `background` e aplicar o `background-position: center`

Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

> **Nota:** `background-position: center` pode ser usado diretamente dentro de `background:`, como no exemplo

```css
.foo {
     width: 100%;
}

.foo .cover {
     /* propriedades para centralizar e assim irá aparar igualmente ambos lados */
     background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD8Pf.jpg) center no-repeat;

     /* a altura exata da imagem */
     height: 1350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Resultou perfeitamente!